# ReferenceError: document is not defined while implementing a search engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, reference

snippet of js: i need to implement a search engine to search for products . I created some json object products. the id productsList represents the list that will be displayed in the search results and the id searchBar represents the search bar and i added the element search bar with its id in all the html files as the search bar is always showing in the application

snippet of html: this file contains the id "productsList"

```js
let products= [
  {"name": "iphone", "img":"/ip hone.jpg", "category":"phones"},
  {"name": "galaxy", "img":"/galaxy.jpg","category":"phones"},
  {"name": "tennis raquet", "img":"/tennis.jpg","category":"sports"},
  {"name": "boxing bag", "img":"/boxing.jpg","category":"sports"},
  {"name": "the sun and her flowers", "img":"/sun.jpg","category":"books"},
  {"name": "leaves of grass", "img":"/leaves.jpg","category":"books"},
]
;

var productsList= document.getElementById('productsList');
var SearchBar= document.getElementById ('searchBar');**
SearchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{
const searchString=e.target.value;
const filteredProducts= products.filter((product)=>{
  return (
        product.name.includes(searchString)|| product.category.includes(searchString)
  );
});
displayProducts(filteredProducts);
});
const displayProducts= (products) => {
const htmlString=characters.map((product) =>{
 return '<li class="product" <h2> ${product.name} </h2> <p> category: ${product.category}</p> <img src="${product.img}"></img> </li>';
}
)
.join('');
productsList.innerHTML= htmlString;
};
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark mb-2">
    <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: rgb(191, 255, 161)">Search Results</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="productsList">
        </ul>
        <form method="POST" action='/search' class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="Search" type="search" placeholder="Search"
                aria-label="Search" id="searchBar">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
<script src= "app.js"></script>
<script type="module"></script>
```

I keep getting the reference error. please help

Comment: Your code crashes with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '**'`, you have extra "**" after `getElementById ('searchBar')`. After removing those, the code still crashes with `Uncaught ReferenceError: characters is not defined`

Comment: @JeremyThille This I fixed for him in the `stackblitz` example, but he still has issues, which seem to be elsewhere as although the example works, it does not work on his side.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the `**` from the `SearchBar` line, the main issue was that it could not find `characters`, by changing this to the property `products`, it could map it properly.

Secondly I added a null check to the `searchString` just incase there is an issue picking up the target value from the HTML.

Herewith the working code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ctaqcu?file=index.js

```js
let products = [
  { name: 'iphone', img: '/ip hone.jpg', category: 'phones' },
  { name: 'galaxy', img: '/galaxy.jpg', category: 'phones' },
  { name: 'tennis raquet', img: '/tennis.jpg', category: 'sports' },
  { name: 'boxing bag', img: '/boxing.jpg', category: 'sports' },
  { name: 'the sun and her flowers', img: '/sun.jpg', category: 'books' },
  { name: 'leaves of grass', img: '/leaves.jpg', category: 'books' },
];

var productsList = document.getElementById('productsList');

var SearchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');

SearchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const searchString = e.target.value;
  if (searchString) {
    const filteredProducts = products.filter((product) => {
      return (
        product.name.includes(searchString) ||
        product.category.includes(searchString)
      );
    });
    displayProducts(filteredProducts);
  }
});

const displayProducts = (products) => {
  const htmlString = products
    .map((product) => {
      return '<li class="product" <h2> ${product.name} </h2> <p> category: ${product.category}</p> <img src="${product.img}"></img> </li>';
    })
    .join('');
  productsList.innerHTML = htmlString;
};
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark mb-2">
  <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: rgb(191, 255, 161)">Search Results</a>
  <button
    class="navbar-toggler"
    type="button"
    data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
    aria-expanded="false"
    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
  >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="productsList"></ul>
    <form method="POST" action="/search" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input
        class="form-control mr-sm-2"
        name="Search"
        type="search"
        placeholder="Search"
        aria-label="Search"
        id="searchBar"
      />
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I took the liberty to copy your external code directly in a snippet in your answer

Comment: thank you very much but unfortunately this does not solve the problem of the reference error of document.getElementById

Comment: also the code is not running in the browser

Comment: The sample was running fine in the `stackblitz` example given, remember we do not have your setup on our machines, nor the same browser or even the same code. We only have the sample code you provided and that worked fine.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ctaqcu?file=index.js

Comment: may i export the project to you?

Comment: Sure, you can add it on a public platform like `stackblitz.com` , `codepen`, or any of the same. Send me the link and I will have a look.

Comment: i understood my problem. i am using node js and express. and i read that. document does not work with node js